# SPARQL - Return mutual objects of a list of subjects

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikidata

How can i get all predicates + objects, which are shared by a list of subjects - without knowing anything about the predicates/objects of these subjects?
Let's look at this example query from Wikidata:

```
SELECT ?chancellor WHERE{
    ?chancellor wdt:P39 wd:Q4970706. #P39 = position held, Q4970706 = Chancellor of Germany
}
```

[Link to this query.](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fchancellor%20%3FchancellorLabel%20WHERE%7B%0A%09%3Fchancellor%20wdt%3AP39%20wd%3AQ4970706.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%09%7D%0A%7D)

This query returns all former chancellors of germany.
**Now i want to return every predicate + object, which every chancellor has in common** e.g. every of the subjects is an instance of human, is born in Germany and whatever.
I guess this is an easy one. However i have no idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good one. Here's a near-hit:

```
prefix wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
prefix wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>

select ?p ?o (count(distinct ?chancellor) as ?cs) where {
    ?chancellor wdt:P39 wd:Q4970706.  
    ?chancellor ?p ?o .
}
group by ?p ?o
order by desc(?cs)
```

[Link to query](https://query.wikidata.org/#prefix%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0Aprefix%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0A%0Aselect%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%28count%28distinct%20%3Fchancellor%29%20as%20%3Fcs%29%20where%20%7B%0A%09%3Fchancellor%20wdt%3AP39%20wd%3AQ4970706.%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fchancellor%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0A%7D%0Agroup%20by%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0Aorder%20by%20desc%28%3Fcs%29%0A)

This takes all chancellors, and their properties and values. It counts the number of chancellors per prop/val.

By ordering that you can see the most common prop / vals at the top.

Now what you want is the only the results for all chancellors. We can get the number of chancellors in one query easily enough, and stick the two together:

```
prefix wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
prefix wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>

select ?p ?o where {
   {
       # Find number of chancellors 
       select (count(?chancellor) as ?num_chancellors) where { 
           ?chancellor wdt:P39 wd:Q4970706
       }
   }
   {
       # Find number of chancellors per predicate / value
       select ?p ?o (count(distinct ?chancellor) as ?chancellor_count) where {
           ?chancellor wdt:P39 wd:Q4970706.  
           ?chancellor ?p ?o .
       }
       group by ?p ?o 
   }
   # Choose results all chancellors share 
   filter (?num_chancellors = ?chancellor_count)
}
```

[Link to query](https://query.wikidata.org/#prefix%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0Aprefix%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0A%0Aselect%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20where%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20select%20%28count%28%3Fchancellor%29%20as%20%3Fnum_chancellors%29%20where%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fchancellor%20wdt%3AP39%20wd%3AQ4970706%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20select%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%28count%28distinct%20%3Fchancellor%29%20as%20%3Fchancellor_count%29%20where%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fchancellor%20wdt%3AP39%20wd%3AQ4970706.%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fchancellor%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20group%20by%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20filter%20%28%3Fnum_chancellors%20%3D%20%3Fchancellor_count%29%0A%7D%0A).

I think this does what you want. Not very pretty, I confess.

Comment: Great answer! Approach #1 is interesting too! #2 is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: It's a shame the query result isn't more interesting :-/ By using group_concat rather than count in the first example you can see which chancellors share prop / vals, which is a useful variation.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting aspect of SPARQL and RDF is that you don't need to know anything about the data to query it.  In your case I'd suggest adding the triple pattern `?chancellor ?p ?o .` and select `?p` and `?o`.  From there you can choose any property you're looking for.  Be sure to use `OPTIONAL` if some of the `?chancellor` matches don't have that property value.

Comment: He wants to get all predicate + object tuples that the chancellors have in common, I don't think that you answered that question.

Comment: Just like @AKSW said, this is not what i'm looking for.